# Was migrate correct for this question?

Tags: discussion, migration

I was recently involved in a question on stack overflow [How do I install Apache/PHP/MySQL onto Mac OS X Lion?](https://serverfault.com/questions/346790/how-do-i-install-apache-php-mysql-onto-mac-os-x-lion) and it was just migrated to Server Fault.

Is Server Fault really the right place for this question? It's not about a server question (installing MySQL on the client version of Mac OS X), and I seriously doubt the person asking this question is a professional of any kind (or he wouldn't need help with something so basic). So it doesn't fit the "Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace" topic.

I feel like it should be moved back to Stack Overflow. But am a bit new to the SE community to be sure.

Comment: Given that it's not in the least bit programming related, at least no more so than the transport a programmer uses to get to work, I'm curios why you think it belongs on SO. It's definitely wrong for SF.

Comment: Question needs more upvotes to encourage polite requests for clarification on migration appropriateness.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers an unposted version of my question actually contained "I'm not sure if it's suitable for stack overflow either" but I removed the line, since it's not very constructive. Thanks for everyone's advice, I'm going to flag it as off topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is SuperUser material, but not because it does not mention the word "server."

The fact that it doesn't mention if his instance of Lion is the server version doesn't discount it immediately. In my experience with Apple Servers, it's not uncommon for Apple SysAdmins to refer to the OS as it's base name and leave off the "server" designation.

(As an aside: That's also equally confusing when people run a legit server with the non "Server" OS because it's not a cut-and-dried case of "Not a Server OS - Instant Close!" It's no less legit than using Debian Etch to run a server off of which could just as easily be running on someone's laptop.)

The fact that the question is at such a basic level, however, does relegate it to SuperUser.

> Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support
> professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a
> professional capacity.

The question, rephrased, says "I cannot perform a basic operation with a basic component of a computer operating system." That is not the earmark of a professional systems administrator. However, I'm not about to make this a discussion about the OP's professional status. Even if he is a professional systems administrator, the fundamental nature of the question does not in any way distinguish it as being for the crowd of people that ServerFault is targeted at.

### Summary

Not distinctly SysAdmin related. Needs to be on SuperUser.

I believe this is a finer case that might be harder to distinguish for someone outside of the SysAdmin / ServerFault realm. Thanks for asking, though!

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm running the "Server" version of Lion on my workstation and it really isn't a server OS. These days it's just a $50 one time purchase (for every machine you own) that adds a few GUI tools to services that are mostly on the client version as well. I can see why people wouldn't bother to add "Server" to the name, especially in Lion.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Exactly. That's also equally confusing when people run a legit server with the non "Server" OS because it's not a cut-and-dried case of "Not a Server OS - Instant Close!" It's no less legit than using Debian Etch to run a server off of which could just as easily be running on someone's laptop.

Answer (score 7):

SO is absolutely famous for migrating to the wrong place (and for migrating questions that should be deleted, haven't read yours so not saying this applies).

Nope, it should have been migrated to [SU] or [Apple.SE]

Comment: I'd go with infamous...